# Convert Excel Formula to T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, excel-formula

I have a Excel formula I am trying to convert to SQL. The Formula is as follows

```
=1800*85%/450*E23
```

Say the value in E23 was 12 then the formula would equal 40.8

In SQL I have written this:

---

```
DECLARE @Number1 INT
DECLARE @Number2 INT
Declare @Number3 INT
Declare @Number4 FLOAT 


Set @Number1 = 1800
Set @Number2 = 85
Set @Number3 = 450

SELECT @Number1 * @Number2 / @Number3 * Column1 AS FormulaResult 
FROM DB;
```

---

If any one could advise how to make @Number2 = 85 into 85% instead, so I could get the same result as I do from Excel I would massively appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: `Set @Number2 = 85/100`

Comment: And `DECLARE @Number2 FLOAT`

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, this make sense.

Comment: But for some reason this returns 0

Comment: FormulaResult
0
0
0

Answer (score 3):

This is simple math. Note: to turn 85 in 85% multiply it by 0.01.

```
DECLARE 
  @Number1 INT,
  @Number2 INT,
  @Number3 INT;
--Declare @Number4 FLOAT; -- don't know what you're doing with this

Set @Number1 = 1800
Set @Number2 = 85
Set @Number3 = 450

DECLARE @DB table (column1 int);
INSERT @DB VALUES (10),(11),(12),(15),(20);

SELECT column1, @Number1 * (@Number2*.01) / @Number3 * column1 AS FormulaResult 
FROM @DB;
```

**Results**

```
column1     FormulaResult
----------- ---------------------------------------
10          34.000000
11          37.400000
12          40.800000
15          51.000000
20          68.000000
```